# Hiding rows according to input box

Tags: excel, vba

I work with large datasets, and I only want to look at rows that contain certain significant data points.  The points I want to look at will be specified according to an inputbox.  So far, I can do things like highlight significant cells, but I cannot get the entire row to hide.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strResult As String
    strResult = InputBox(Prompt:="Please Enter Number", Title:="Data Entry:")
    Set r = Range("A:B")

    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <= strResult Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: If you set breakpoints, what part of the code does it run to? What effect does it have? Does the input box show up? I tried that code and it works as you expected it to.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work from looking at it. Have you tried dimensioning `r` and `cell` as `Range`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider inputting a **number**

```
    Dim strResult As Long
    strResult = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Enter Number", Title:="Data Entry:", Type:=1)
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:B"))
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <= strResult Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
```

Answer (score -1):

You May Try This It will Surely Work For You

```
Private Sub Hide_btn_Click()    
h = InputBox("Enter Column start Range to Hide the Column - Example A:C")    
Columns((h)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True    
End Sub
```

You can Give the Conditions Also

Thanks